# Why am I getting SaveError: Variable does not exist: AssigneeId?

Tags: dml, permission-sets

I have entered the following code entered in the Force.com IDE:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/PermissionSetAssignment2/*')
global with sharing class PermissionSetAssignment {

    @HttpPost
    global static String assignPermissionSet(String assigneeId, String permissionSetName) {
        String permissionSetId;

        // Get the Id of the Permission Set identified by permissionSetName    
        String query = 'SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet WHERE name = :permissionSetName';
        sObject s = Database.query(query);
        permissionSetId = s.Id;

        PermissionSetAssignment permAssignment = new PermissionSetAssignment();
        permAssignment.AssigneeId = assigneeId; 
        permAssignment.PermissionSetId = permissionSetId;

        insert permAssignment;

        return 'string';
    }

}
```

And I get the following error:

> Save error: Variable does not exist: AssigneeId   PermissionSetAssignment.cls /DDApexRest/src/classes line 14

And yet the documentation clearly states that AssigneeId is an attribute of PermissionSetAssignment.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The class name PermissionSetAssignment may be hiding the object name PermissionSetAssignment. Change the class name slighty or prefix the SObject references with schema. e.g. schema.PermissionSetAssignment.

Comment: Keith is correct - it works for me setting the value assigneeid, so it must be your class of the same name interfering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class name is `PermissionSetAssignment`, this is hiding the SObject type of same name.

The error is telling you that your `PermissionSetAssignment` class does not have an `AssigneeId` property.

I'd recommend not naming any classes or variables the same as any standard objects to avoid this in future.